# Gcloud json format get not the full url of machine tpye

Tags: json, bash, jq, gcloud

Running a gcloud query and trying to get the output of the json to only include the actual machine type in stead of the full url.

```
gcloud compute instances list --project $projectname --format=json | jq -r '.[]| .name +","+.machineType'
```

Which prints out as

```
$instancename,https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$projectname/zones/europe-west2-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-4
```

It currently prints out the full machineType, wondering if anyone knows of a way to short the url to get just the machine type as the string instead of the full url.

I've got this sed as well to clear the format but how does one apply to only the second string without deleting the name `sed 's@.*/@@'`

Thanks in advance

edit: found some potential with split in jq

```
gcloud compute instances list --project $projectname --format=json | jq -r '.[]|(.machineType|split("https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/"))'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Cloud SDK (gcloud) topic formats:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#scope

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(machineType.scope(machineTypes))"
```

> **NOTE** You asked how to do this with `gcloud` and this is the way. @rsalinas' point is good. There's a philosophy that tech should "do one thing well" and `gcloud`'s formatting|filtering break this. Personally, I prefer to `gcloud ... --format=json | jq .` and use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to process `gcloud` output partly because I can use the same theory with `kubectl`, `doctl` etc. etc. etc. `awk` is another magical tool that is generally useful.

Comment: This is useful thanks! You mentioned with jq? How would you slice up the string with jq? I can't seem to find anything in the docs except for split, which doesn't really seem to workout. Using it to write some html, so currently looking like this `gcloud compute instances list --project $project --format=json | jq -r '.[]|"<td>"+.name+"</td><td>"+.networkInterfaces[].networkIP+"</td><td>,"+.machineType+"</td></tr>"'` just can't get the machineType smaller. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Assuming (!) that the service always returns URLs of the form `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${project}/zones/${zone}/machineTypes/${machineType}` perhaps `jq -r '.[].machineType|split("/")|.[10]`?

Comment: Please consider marking my original answer as accepted, if it is.

Comment: ah nice thats pretty neat! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this, but I would recommend you to just do it with `awk` since you can use the `,` and then `/` as the separators from the output of the command.

You can use something like this based on the command you shared:
`gcloud compute instances list --project $projectname --format=json | jq -r '.[]| .name +","+.machineType' | awk -F',' '{print $1"/"$2}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1"="$12}'`.

And you would get `$instance-name=$machine-type`

Hope you find this useful.